# How to create a Query to search at 2 workspaces in Magnolia?

Tags: sql, workspace, magnolia

I am trying to create a query so I can search for assets that have been published in Magnolia but that are inside of pages that had not been published.

I created a query for those assets that have been published to search inside the 'dam' repository wiht JRC-SQL2:

```
select p.* 
  from [mgnl:asset] as p 
 where (ISDESCENDANTNODE('/demo-features/tests') 
        or ISSAMENODE('/demo-features/tests')) 
   and (p.[mgnl:activationStatus] <> '')
```

but when I try to add any sort of extra condition to search in the 'website' repository in order to check if the asset exists there, I have been unable to create one that works.

I tried with UNION, IN, INNER JOIN, but because the information I seek it's in another repository Magnolia does not permit me to reach it.

Could any of you point me a way to reach information from 2 repositories at the same time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each workspace and each repository has it's own index. Therefore you can't combine searching over them in single query.

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer, If its not posible to create a query to search simultaneously in two different is there any node or property inside of an asset that will permit me to know if they are being used by a page without having to get their "ID" and search for it in the "website" repository?.

Comment: There's content dependency module that allows you to do that. https://documentation.magnolia-cms.com/display/DOCS56/Content+Dependencies+module

Comment: Thank you for your time, at the end i was unable to create the Dependencies neccesaries to form the connections through the repositories, but one of my coworkers thinks that this is the correct path to create the desired connection and i the future we will have to revisit this issue, but thanks for your tip and time anyway.